# How to find the means of consecutive numbers in a column given consecutive string of another column in r

Tags: r, mean

I have a dataset that looks similar to this:

```
head(df,20)
   mmpd tot
1     0   0
2    mm   0
3    mm   1
4     0   0
5     0   0
6    mm   0
7    mm   1
8    mm   3
9    mm   1
10    0   0
11    0   0
12    0   0
13    0   0
14   mm   0
15   mm   0
16    0   0
17    0   0
18   mm   4
19   mm   1
20   mm   0
```

I would like to get the average of df$tot when it corresponds to a string of mm in df$mmpd.  So for the example dataset, I'd like to get the following string of numbers: .5, 1.25, 0, 1.667.  df$mmpd will always either be a string of mm > 1, or 0, and the column can begin with either 0 or a string of mm.

Is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.5+
setDT(df)[,.(my=mean(tot)), by=.(indx=rleid(mmpd),mmpd)][,indx:=NULL][mmpd=='mm']
   mmpd       my
#1:   mm 0.500000
#2:   mm 1.250000
#3:   mm 0.000000
#4:   mm 1.666667
```

Apparently, there are many ways to do it (see [r search along a vector and calculate the mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685733/r-search-along-a-vector-and-calculate-the-mean/30685760#30685760)). The `data.table` method was fastest and adapted here.

Note: `rleid` can be use outside of the `data.table` syntax. This will be more like "traditional" `R` syntax and produce the same results.

```
subset(aggregate(tot ~ indx + mmpd, 
          data=cbind(df,indx=rleid(df$mmpd)),
          FUN=mean),mmpd=="mm")
```

Speed comparison of different ways to generate rleid (myrleid
 is from @JasonAizkalns answer).

```
> set.seed(1); x<-sample(1:2,100000,replace=T); 
  microbenchmark(rleid(x),
                 myrleid2=cumsum(c(1,diff(x)!=0)),
                 myrleid(x))
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
   rleid(x) 1.422263 1.500873 1.586482 1.571315 1.662982  1.938254   100 a  
   myrleid2 3.860290 3.908308 4.369646 3.962497 4.177673 15.674611   100  b 
 myrleid(x) 7.282868 7.386515 7.753515 7.444008 7.654126 18.864898   100   c
```

For non-numeric x:

```
>  set.seed(1); x<-sample(c('a','b'),100000,replace=T); 
>  microbenchmark(rleid(x),myrleid2=cumsum(c(1,diff(as.numeric(factor(x)))!=0)),myrleid(x))
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
   rleid(x)  1.465466  1.571662  1.684568  1.606614  1.66080  2.900983   100 a
   myrleid2  8.705447  9.276787 12.393393  9.907403 10.35032 61.080374   100  b
 myrleid(x) 11.970271 13.176144 18.779256 13.790767 14.09626 69.845587   100   c
```

Comment: Ooh, didn't know about `rleid`, that's a nicely convenient function.

Comment: Yes, it is very useful as it is way faster than `rle`.

Comment: `rleid()` is also designed to work with more than one column.. e.g., `rleid(a,b,c)`.

Comment: Wow @fishtank very elegant.  I was not aware of the `rleid` function either @Arun

Answer (score 1):

Using this data:

```
df = structure(list(mmpd = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"mm"), class = "factor"), tot = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("mmpd", 
"tot"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Add a grouping column (only needs to be valid for "mm" values)

```
df$group = cumsum(df$mmpd != "mm")
```

For the "mm" subset of the data, take the groupwise means:

```
tapply(df$tot[df$mmpd == "mm"], INDEX = group[df$mmpd == "mm"], FUN = mean)
#        1        3        7        9 
# 0.500000 1.250000 0.000000 1.666667
```

The group indices don't make a ton of sense (they increment by the number of intervening zeroes minus one), but you weren't asking for them anyway and the result is correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using base `R` -- roll-your-own `relid()` function inspired by the one in the `data.table` package:

```
myrleid <- function(x) {
  x <- rle(x)$lengths
  rep(seq_along(x), times=x)
}
```

Then make a `group` variable using this function and use `aggregate`:

```
df$group <- myrleid(df$mmpd)
aggregate(data = subset(df, mmpd == "mm"), tot ~ group, mean)

#   group      tot
# 1     2 0.500000
# 2     4 1.250000
# 3     6 0.000000
# 4     8 1.666667
```

Comment: It is faster to use `cumsum(c(1,diff(x)!=0))` to define `myrleid`.

Comment: @fishtank cool and thanks for the benchmarking, but how would that work in this case where we have a non-numeric column?

Comment: It would still work using `as.numeric(factor(x))`. Tested it still faster.